# Gradle Multi Module jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following project config (pure java):

```
/
/Base_module
/A_module
```

A_module depends on Base_module.

I want a *.jar* containing the A_module classes **+** the Base_module classes, but can't make it.

With the following config, I can only achieve different jars for each module:

settings.gradle

```
include 'Base_module', 'A_module'
```

build.gradle

```
....
project(':Base_module') {
}

project(':A_module') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':Base_module')
    }
}
....
```

What do I need to add to achieve the full *.jar*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what about the dependencies section in your root build.gradle?

Comment: dependencies is empty on root build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a custom task of Jar type in your root build script, which will include all the classes of all subprojects or just a number of subprojects. It could be something similar to:

```
//declare an array, containing subproject names, which classes you want to collect
def projectsToCollect = [':Base_Module',':A_Module']

//create a custom task, which assembles an jar-archive and depends on subproject compilation tasks, 
//that causes sibprojects sources been compiled before thist task runs
task singleJar( type: Jar , dependsOn: projectsToCollect.collect{ it+":compileJava"}) {
    //set new jar name
    baseName = 'singleJar'
    //set files, which will be included in this new jar
    from files(projectsToCollect.collect{ project(it).sourceSets.main.output })
}
```

You can play it around, modifying sourcesets, if you have some custom in your subprojects, or if you want to add tests.

Comment: would you please clarify a bit each part of the code? I'm not a Gradle expert, and can't get my head arount it

Comment: @Cheborra tried to clarify alittle, if you haven't changed your sourcesets, since you don't know about it, this solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

That would be fatJar aka uberJar aka shadowJar

take a look at https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

You would need to configure for you `':A_module'` project